# Websocket Handling in Kong Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, google-kubernetes-engine, kong

I have kong and konga in my GKE (Kubernetes). I deployed them using helm chart. I want to handle a websocket service (it deployed on GKE too but on different cluster with kong and konga) using kong because it will be a microservice in there. If i'm accessing the websocket service using it's own Load Balancer IP, the websocket is worked. But if i access it on kong path, the websocket throw 403 forbidden.

[kong-websocket-network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E34M8.png)

I have make a yaml to add a websocket plugin for kong. The yaml file look like this:

```
# WebSocket plugin
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
  name: websocket-plugin
config:
  protocols:
    - websocket
plugin: websocket
```

But it throws an error: admission webhook "validations.kong.konghq.com" denied the request: plugin failed schema validation: schema violation (name: plugin 'websocket' not enabled; add it to the 'plugins' configuration property).

Also i have tried to add a header "Connection: Upgrade" and "Upgrade: WebSocket", but it still didn't affect anything.

Can anyone help me with it? Thank you in advance!!!

note: if you want to check the websocket, you can use this url

http://34.101.32.121:8080/